# nameref does not work with LLNCS

Tags: lncs, nameref

I'm trying to use the very practicle `nameref` package with lncs (sty file downloaded [here](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip)). Unfortunately, instead of displaying the actual name of the definition, it displays the name of last section. Any idea why?

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}
%\documentclass{article} %% <== works with article/below definitions
%% Already defined in LLNCS
% \usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, amsmath}
% \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\providecommand*\definitionautorefname{Definition}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{The name of the section}

\begin{definition}[Nice name for my definition]\label{def:propertiesF}
  I am a nice definition with a nice name
\end{definition}


\section{Use of nameref}

The following nameref should display ``Nice name for my definition''. But the display is \nameref{def:propertiesF}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `llncs` class defines theorem-like environments with `\spnewtheorem` and `nameref` is unable to hook into them as it does when `amsthm` (or the vanilla LaTeX `\newtheorem`).

You have to make a hook yourself.

```latex
\documentclass{llncs}

\providecommand*\definitionautorefname{Definition}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\ORIGINAL@spythm\@spythm
\def\@spythm#1#2#3#4[#5]{%
  \NR@gettitle{#5}%
  \ORIGINAL@spythm{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}[#5]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{The name of the section}

\begin{definition}[Nice name for my definition]\label{def:propertiesF}
  I am a nice definition with a nice name
\end{definition}


\section{Use of nameref}

The following nameref should display ``Nice name for my definition''. 
And it does: \nameref{def:propertiesF}.

\end{document}
```

[image]